# MinIfs with Array Slice

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, slice

I assign a range from a table to an 2-D array and then perform some analyses with that array.

The array is of the variant type with columns 3, 4 and 5 containing the Item Name, Date and a value. The layout is similar to the following:

```
Column 3    Column 4    Column 5
Item A      01/09/1987  0
Item A      01/10/1987  0
Item A      01/11/1987  1455
Item A      01/12/1987  1863
Item A      01/01/1988  1882
Item A      01/02/1988  1890
Item A      01/03/1988  0
Item A      01/04/1988  0
Item A      01/05/1988  0
Item B      01/09/1987  0
Item B      01/10/1987  2041
Item B      01/11/1987  1130
Item B      01/12/1987  1452
Item B      01/01/1988  1863
Item B      01/02/1988  1683
Item B      01/03/1988  1605
Item B      01/04/1988  1614
Item B      01/05/1988  1544
```

I create a Temporary Array (the global array is way above the 65k items limit of the functions that I need) assigning the corresponding dates and values for one Item at a time.

I then try using the Minifs function, as follows:

```
KPIMat(jCount, 3) = Application.WorksheetFunction.MinIfs( _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(TempArr1, 0, 4), _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Index(TempArr1, 0, 5), _
    ">0")
```

The KPIMat is an array to store the data KPI.

I get

> Run-Time Error 424, Object Required

I think the Minifs function expects a range and I am passing a 1D array.

I have been trying to find a code-based solution, other than writing my own UDF to solve this problem.

Comment: Iterate the array rows and do your own check and store the new min in a new variable.  it will be quick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you found MINIFS wants a range and not an array.

Just iterate the Array yourself and use a temp variable:

```
Dim minTemp As double
minTemp = 1E+99

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(TempArr1, 1) To UBound(TempArr1,1)
    If temparr(i, 5) > 0 And temparr(i, 4) < minTemp Then
        minTemp = temparr(i, 4)
    End If
Next i

KPIMat(jCount, 3) = minTemp
```

Comment: Thank you for confirming this. I found it bizarre that the function Min can indeed manage the array but the MinIfs cannot. I will do as you suggest.